# Turning a string into a list of variables

Tags: string, list, python-2.7

I have some variables like

```
X=[1,2,3]
Y=[1,2,0]
Z=[2,1,0]
```

I need to turn a list like `['X','X','Y','Z','Y','X']` into something that reads those variables e.g. `[X,X,Y,Z,Y,X]`